# Using a Z test to place a confidence interval on a population proportion in practice

Tags: statistics

My understanding is that using a Z test to place a confidence interval on a population proportion makes sense so long as the underlying random variable's distribution is binomial, that is, there is a fixed probability of success p on any trial & trials are independent of each other. My understanding is also that this technique of placing a confidence interval on a population proportion is used in practice when polling a population for their stance on a political issue (e.g. do you support background checks on gun owners?).

If I think about flipping a coin, it's rather clear that there is a fixed probability p of success on any one trial & trials are independent of each other.

If I think about someone's stance on a political issue, it's not really like that. The person either does or does not support background checks on gun owners.

I guess the part that is supposed to be binomial (fixed probability of "success" & independent trials) is the sampling part. Which person out of the population is chosen! Is this why a binomial distribution is a valid assumption to make? The statistician introduces the randomness by sampling carefully.

Are there other proportion estimates problems in which using a Z test to place a confidence interval on the proportion would NOT be acceptable, since the underlying distribution is decidedly NOT binomial? e.g. I would guess that the # of baskets scored by a basketball player in n trials wouldn't follow a binomial distribution; there is much more going on.

Comment: Assume that there are $n$ people, $k$ of which support background checks. Pick a person at random. The probability that he supports is $\frac{k}{n}$, which is practically a coin flip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the coin flip example, the source of randomness is from the subtle differences in the initial physical conditions that vary from flip to flip; e.g., the exact amount of force, the initial position of the coin, etc.  If you could theoretically replicate exactly these conditions each time you toss the coin, you would eliminate the randomness of the outcome.  If you could even substantially reduce the variability in these conditions, or reduce their impact on the outcome, you would also reduce the randomness.

In the polling example, the source of randomness is the sampling process itself, not the response of a given experimental unit (i.e. polled person).  If you sample a group of people randomly and obtain some set of outcomes, and then I go and sample the exact same group of people and they give me the same answers as they gave you, then my data will be identical to yours, and no additional information is gained as a result.  That's because while your sampling was random, mine was not.  Another example is if you knew the views of certain people in advance, and decided only to ask them.  This would not be random sampling.

In each case, randomness is generated by allowing some underlying process--be it reliant on physics or sampling--to vary from experiment to experiment in such a way that the observed outcome is not predetermined and is, in the long run, expected to be faithful to or representative of the true overall characteristics of the population being observed.  In the coin flip experiment, the population is the infinite set of all coin flips.  In the polling experiment, the population is the finite (but large) set of all voters.